# Xcode iOS17 Simulator and GRDB - Class ... is implemented in both ... One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, grdb, xcode15, ios17

I have a Swift and SwiftUI app using GRDB and GRDBQuery that has been working well. (Thank you Gwendal Roué.) When I run the app using Xcode 15 beta and the iOS17 simulator, I get 42 new messages in the log when the app starts. The messages all relate to GRDB classes and are of the same form but referring to different classes. The first two are:

objc[23081]: Class _TtC4GRDB18SQLStatementCursor is implemented in both /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21A5248u/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GRDB.framework/GRDB (0x1c0be3ea8) and /Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/55E0C4E1-F07E-4647-A897-E7B3CCFDDB93/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3171E5C3-F01A-4C91-B6EA-9C60A757F3C4/AppName.app/AppName (0x104de56d8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[23081]: Class _TtC4GRDB8Database is implemented in both /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21A5248u/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GRDB.framework/GRDB (0x1c0be4d88) and /Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/55E0C4E1-F07E-4647-A897-E7B3CCFDDB93/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3171E5C3-F01A-4C91-B6EA-9C60A757F3C4/AppName.app/AppName (0x104de58e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Running the same app under Xcode 15 beta on an iOS16 simulator, does not produce the messages. I have added GRDB and GRDBQuery using "Add Package Dependencies", i.e. using Swift Package Manager. I have tried removing the packages and adding them again. I have tried cleaning build folder and deleting the DerivedData folder.

Any ideas on what to try next would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried creating a new project from scratch and adding my source files. I still have the same issue.

Comment: I have now created a new project in Xcode and without making any changes to the default hello world source code, I have added the GRDB package. This project also displays the same 42 error messages in the log.

Comment: I have now raised this as an issue on the GRDB Github page. However, it may be considered a SPM, Xcode or iOS17 simulator issue there.

Comment: Same question on Apple developer forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/732192